# How to use a extension point from a jar file in eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have a plugin in eclipse, in which I am using a extension point name "com.quantix.qapi.actions". That extension point is available inside a jar file and I have added that jar file to the build path of the project.
But I am getting a Unknown extension point error in eclipse.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>
<extension point="com.quantix.qapi.actions">
...
</extension>
</plugin>
```

ERROR:

```
Unknown extension point: 'com.quantix.qapi.actions'
```

But in the same file I am using a another extension which is available inside another project in a eclipse.And I have added that project as a dependency to this one.And I am not getting any error there.

```xml
<extension point="com.idbs.ewb.extensions.experimentItemMenuHandlers">
...
</extension>
```

Is it anything to do with the jar file reference. I am not able to find the exact problem.

Answer (score 1):

Extension points must be defined in the `plugin.xml` file for the plugin. Eclipse will not look in jars in the build path for extension points.

It sounds like the jar you have may be a plugin. You should add it to your Target Platform or import it using 'File > Import > Plug-in Development > Plug-ins and Fragments'. Then add the plugin to the dependencies of your plugin.

Comment: yes it is a plugin...Bur i don't have the source code for it to import.i only have the jar file

Comment: You don't need the source code for either of these options

Comment: If the jar is a plugin then Import Plug-ins and Fragments will import it as a binary only plugin.Or you can add it to your target platform if you have one set up (and you should).